# Android Video Circular Buffer with Sound

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediacodec, grafika

I am using Google's Open Source Example: **[Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)**. I am using it's **[ContinuousCaptureActivity.java](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)** The CircularBuffer's Implementation is demonstrated in this Activity, but there is no audio included in the resultant Video file.

I want to add the Audio Recording functionality within this Activity and add the recorded Audio into the Video in the same CircularBuffered Fashion.

For achieving this i have explored the MediaCodec Library, which was introduced in 4.3+ versions. I have also used MediaMuxer to capture Video and Audio Streams and Muxed them into a single Video.

But, I am not sure about how to implement the Audio Recording functionality into the `ContinuousCaptureActivity.java` class. Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: Hey @Salman have you done this ?? if yes then please help me at this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494059/how-to-add-audio-to-video-while-recording-continuouscaptureactivity-grafika)**