# How to add Audio to Video while Recording [ContinuousCaptureActivity] [Grafika]

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, grafika

I implement Video recording using **[ContinuousCaptureActivity.java](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java)**. it's work perfectly.

Now i want to add Audio in this video.

I know using [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) it is possible to add audio in video.

But the problem is i don't know how to i use `MediaMuxer`.

Also if you have any other solution without `MediaMuxer` then share with me any link or doc.

also i have demo **[AudioVideoRecordingSample](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample)**. But i don't understand how to i merge this with my code.

please explain to me if anyone knows.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Merging Audio File and Video File**

```
private void muxing() {

String outputFile = "";

try {

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "final2.mp4");
file.createNewFile();
outputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();

MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
AssetFileDescriptor afdd = getAssets().openFd("Produce.MP4");
videoExtractor.setDataSource(afdd.getFileDescriptor() ,afdd.getStartOffset(),afdd.getLength());

MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
audioExtractor.setDataSource(audioFilePath);

Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount() );
Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount() );

MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString() );
Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString() );

boolean sawEOS = false;
int frameCount = 0;
int offset = 100;
int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

muxer.start();

while (!sawEOS)
{
    videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
    videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


    if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
        sawEOS = true;
        videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

    }
    else
    {
        videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
        videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.getSampleFlags();
        muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
        videoExtractor.advance();


        frameCount++;
        Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
        Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

    }
}

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



boolean sawEOS2 = false;
int frameCount2 =0;
while (!sawEOS2)
{
    frameCount2++;

    audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
    audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

    if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
        sawEOS2 = true;
        audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
        audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags();
        muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
        audioExtractor.advance();


        Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
        Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

    }
}

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

muxer.stop();
muxer.release();


} catch (IOException e) {
Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 1 " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 2 " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**For Samples Visit**  [here](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeAndMuxTest)

Comment: OP asked about adding an audio source to a live, continuous capture. It isn't a question about how to mux audio file with video file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am late.  this is what you want.

https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk

It also implemented encoding with MediaCodec and upload video stream with ffmpeg.